Odoo Image Field on Mobile Opens Gallery Instead of Camera
I have created an Odoo form module that contains image fields. When I try to open this form on a mobile device and upload an image, it always opens the gallery by default, without providing the option to take a picture using the camera.
There is no option to choose the camera to take a new photo.
On mobile devices, when clicking the image field, the user should be able to choose between using the camera or opening the gallery to select an image.
